# Camera-space Normals from depth texture

Tags: opengl, glsl, lighting, normals, deferred-rendering

I want to use a stored (non-linear) depth texture from 1st pass to produce screen-space normals. In 2nd pass I can render out depth, diffuse, ID etc., but I can't seem to get normals from depth working.

Current understanding of getting normals from depth:

1. `texture()` / `texelFetch()` `p` at the current tex coord, `p` + (1, 0) = `p1`, and `p` + (0, 1) = `p2`; reconstruct camera-space positions from these
2. Get `v1` vector `p1 - p`: vector between current position and it's screen/texture-space x neighbour
3. Get `v2` vector `p2 - p`: vector between current position and it's screen/texture-space y neighbour
4. `cross` product these two and `normalize()` to get the surface normal at current texel.

**Shaders (2nd pass! render to fullscreen quad)**

Vertex:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texcoord;

out vec2 texcoordFrag;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, 0, 1);
    texcoordFrag = texcoord;
}
```

Fragment:

```
#version 330 core

uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform mat4 vpInv;

in vec2 texcoordFrag;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 fragmentColor;


float near = 0.1;
float far = 100.0;

float linearizeDepth(float depth)
{
    float nearToFarDistance = far - near;
    return (2.0 * near) / (far + near - depth * nearToFarDistance);
    //http://www.ozone3d.net/blogs/lab/20090206/how-to-linearize-the-depth-value/ 
    //http://www.geeks3d.com/20091216/geexlab-how-to-visualize-the-depth-buffer-in-glsl/
} 

vec3 worldSpacePositionFromDepth(in float depth)
{
    vec4 clipSpacePos;
    clipSpacePos.xy = texcoordFrag * 2.0 - 1.0;
    clipSpacePos.z = texture(tex, texcoordFrag).r * 2.0 - 1.0;
    clipSpacePos.w = 1.0;
    vec4 homogenousPos = vpInv * clipSpacePos;
    return homogenousPos.xyz / homogenousPos.w;
}

vec3 viewSpacePositionFromDepth(in float depth) //PositionFromDepth_DarkPhoton(): https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/176040-Render-depth-to-texture-issue
{
    vec2 ndc;             // Reconstructed NDC-space position
    vec3 eye;             // Reconstructed EYE-space position

    float top = 0.05463024898; //per 1 radianm FoV & distance of 0.1
    float bottom = -top;

    float right = top * 1024.0 / 768.0;
    float left = -right;

    float width = 1024.0;
    float height = 768.0;
    float widthInv = 1.0 / width;
    float heightInv = 1.0 / height;

    ndc.x = (texcoordFrag.x - 0.5) * 2.0;
    ndc.y = (texcoordFrag.y - 0.5) * 2.0;

    eye.z = linearizeDepth(depth); //eye.z = near * far / ((depth * (far - near)) - far); //original
    eye.x = (-ndc.x * eye.z) * right/near;
    eye.y = (-ndc.y * eye.z) * top/near;

    return eye;
}

vec3 getNormal(vec3 p1, vec3 p2)
{
    vec3 normal = cross(p2, p1);
    normal.z = -normal.z;
    return normalize(normal) * 0.5 + 0.5;
}   

void main()
{
    float depth  = texture(tex, texcoordFrag.st).r;
    float depth1 = texture(tex, texcoordFrag.st + vec2(1.0/1024.0, 0)).r;
    float depth2 = texture(tex, texcoordFrag.st + vec2(1.0/768.0 , 0)).r;
    float depthLinear = linearizeDepth(depth);

    if (depthLinear > 1.0) discard;
    //fragmentColor = vec4(depth, depth, depth, 1.0f);
    fragmentColor = vec4(depthLinear, depthLinear, depthLinear, 1.0);

    //vec3 w = worldSpacePositionFromDepth(depth);
    //fragmentColor = vec4(w, 1.0);

    vec3 p  = viewSpacePositionFromDepth(depth);
    vec3 p1 = viewSpacePositionFromDepth(depth1);
    vec3 p2 = viewSpacePositionFromDepth(depth2);

    vec3 v1 = (p1-p);
    vec3 v2 = (p2-p);
    vec3 normal = getNormal(v1, v2);
    fragmentColor = vec4(normal, 1.0);
}
```

**Result**

[image]

**Question** What am I doing wrong? Explain it like you would to a five year old.:)

This will be used as a basis for SSAO and directional lighting.

As far as I know, `dFdx` and `dFdy` are not the answer as I am working with texels, not fragments.

Comment: ...because storing normals in another texture is too easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you calculate `p`, `p1` and `p2` via `viewSpacePositionFromDepth` is certainly wrong. That function uses *the same* `texcoordFrag` for all three points, just with a different depth, so all three points will lie on a line. The cross product in `getNormal` should just yield 0 for any pixel - what you see here are just numerical instability, which is amplified by normalizing the resulting vector to unit lenght.

Comment: Thanks; it seems all I needed was some code review! I was blind to such an obvious problem. It is _apparently_ working now, irrespective of whether or not I used dFdx/dFdy or manual diffs. I will award the bounty once I have SSAO running on this basis -- I just want to be certain the normals are now correct in terms of direction. It certainly appears so.